# shared context between functions (entity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

For once i'm not here because i have a problem, but a question regarding entity

i have a class named db that makes all the entity calls.
because i'm lazy all the functions are static.
a process for one function may result in other function calls in this class...
creating a new object MyDBEntities each time, probably without the modifications that did not get through a saveChanges()

is it a good idea to "share" the context between all the functions?
let me explain: I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429312/entity-framework-code-first-shared-and-instance-context) and i don't want to do something like this but something more like:

```
private static MyDBEntities context(MyDBEntities c)
{
    if (c == null)
        c = new MyDBEntities();
    return c;
}
```

and each function like

```
public static randomfunction(object parameter1,MyDBEntities ctx = null )
{
    ctx=context(ctx);
    /*things*/
    randomfunction2(blablah,ctx);
    /*awesome stuff*/
}
```

could it be a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Don't be lazy. Treat DbContext as unit of work - create it when you need it and dispose it afterwards. When reusing an instance - it may hog your memory because it will track more entities than you want to. You can also inadvertently save changes you did not want to save if one of the methods leaves the context dirty.